# error al subir archivos de gran tamaño con google_service_drive_drivefile

Tags: php, google-api

estoy usando la api de google para subir archivos a drive
los sube correctamente en local pero en produccion solo sube los archivos ligeros.

```
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name'=> $nombre_estudio));
       // $content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
        $createdFile = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
            'uploadType' => 'Resumable',
            'fields' => 'id, webContentLink'));
```

acabo de cambiar `'uploadType' => 'Resumable',` tenia anteriormente `multipart`

**este codigo lo modifique por que no agregaba los archivos**

```
function insertaArchivoDrive($service, $nombre_estudio, $folderId, $data){
        // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setName($nombre_estudio);
        $file->setDescription('A test zip');
        $file->setMimeType('application/zip');
        if(isset($folderId)){                     
            $file->setParents(array($folderId));    
        }

        /*$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
              'data' => $data,
              'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
              'uploadType' => 'multipart',
              'fields' => 'id, webContentLink'
            ));

            printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);*/
        // echo "createdFile" . "<br/>";

        $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name'=> $nombre_estudio));
       // $content = file_get_contents('files/photo.jpg');
        $createdFile = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
            'uploadType' => 'Resumable',
            'fields' => 'id, webContentLink'));
        //printf("File IDd: %s\n", $createdFile->id);

        return $createdFile;

    }
```

`$file` lo cambie por `$fileMetadata` y con esto pude agregar los archivos a drive y guardar el registro en la base de datos.

/////**nuevo codigo**

```
  function leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo){
        $totalBytes = 0;
        $pedazoGigante = "";
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $pedazo = fread($fp, 8192);
            $totalBytes += strlen($pedazo);
            $pedazoGigante .= $pedazo;
            if ($totalBytes >= $bytesDelPedazo) {
                return $pedazoGigante;
            }
        }
        return $pedazoGigante;
    }
    $archivoDrive = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $archivoDrive->setName($nombre_estudio);
    $archivoDrive->setDescription('A test zip');
    $archivoDrive->setMimeType('application/zip');



    $bytesDelPedazo = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //128Kbs

    $paramsOpc = array(
        'fields' => '*'
    );

    $this->client->setDefer(true);
    $solicitud = $service->files->create($archivoDrive,$paramsOpc);        
    $multimedia = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $this->client,
        $solicitud,
        "application/zip",
        null,
        true,
        $bytesDelPedazo
    );
    $multimedia->setFileSize(filesize($ruta));

    $estado = false;
    $fp = fopen($ruta, "rb");
    while (!$estado && !feof($fp)) {
        // leemos hasta que dejamos de obtener $bytesDelPedazo del $archivoLocal
        $pedazo = leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo);
        $estado = $multimedia->nextChunk($pedazo);
    }
    var_dump($archivoDrive);
    return $archivoDrive;
```

si lo dejo haci me inserta todos los campos excepto id de carpeta folder de la carpeta

si agrego estas dos lineas no me inserta nada en la base

```
$archivoDrive->setId($folderId);
    $archivoDrive->setParents(array($folderId));
```

esto es lo qjue me imprime archivoDrive

```
file_get_contents
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#57 (64) { ["collection_key":protected]=> string(6) "spaces" ["appProperties"]=> NULL ["capabilitiesType":protected]=> string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities" ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["contentHintsType":protected]=> string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints" ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["createdTime"]=> NULL ["description"]=> string(10) "A test zip" ["explicitlyTrashed"]=> NULL ["fileExtension"]=> NULL ["folderColorRgb"]=> NULL ["fullFileExtension"]=> NULL ["hasAugmentedPermissions"]=> NULL ["hasThumbnail"]=> NULL ["headRevisionId"]=> NULL ["iconLink"]=> NULL ["id"]=> NULL ["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=> string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata" ["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["isAppAuthorized"]=> NULL ["kind"]=> NULL ["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User" ["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["md5Checksum"]=> NULL ["mimeType"]=> string(15) "application/zip" ["modifiedByMe"]=> NULL ["modifiedByMeTime"]=> NULL ["modifiedTime"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(19) "FiraCode-master.zip" ["originalFilename"]=> NULL ["ownedByMe"]=> NULL ["ownersType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User" ["ownersDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array" ["parents"]=> NULL ["permissionsType":protected]=> string(31) "Google_Service_Drive_Permission" ["permissionsDataType":protected]=> string(5) "array" ["properties"]=> NULL ["quotaBytesUsed"]=> NULL ["shared"]=> NULL ["sharedWithMeTime"]=> NULL ["sharingUserType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User" ["sharingUserDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["size"]=> NULL ["spaces"]=> NULL ["starred"]=> NULL ["teamDriveId"]=> NULL ["thumbnailLink"]=> NULL ["thumbnailVersion"]=> NULL ["trashed"]=> NULL ["trashedTime"]=> NULL ["trashingUserType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User" ["trashingUserDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["version"]=> NULL ["videoMediaMetadataType":protected]=> string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata" ["videoMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["viewedByMe"]=> NULL ["viewedByMeTime"]=> NULL ["viewersCanCopyContent"]=> NULL ["webContentLink"]=> NULL ["webViewLink"]=> NULL ["writersCanShare"]=> NULL ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } FILEID:
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: no me genera un error el archivo no se sube a drive  si es mayor a 40 megas

Comment: @Morfinismo que informacion necesitas para poder ayudarme a solucionar este problema?

Comment: Normalmente, siempre hay un error, pero si no hay alguno en tu caso, no queda más que intentar replicar el problema. Una duda... ¿es cuenta de consumidor de gmail o es cuenta de G Suite?

Comment: es de G suite estoy buscando algun error que mande en local en estos momentos si encuentro algun error aviso, tengo una teoria que el error podria ser por Resumable o multipart como mencione anteriormente solo con archivos mayor a 30 megas es donde no termina el proceso

Comment: no me marca ningun error si subo archivos de hasta 50 megas en local si me los sube correctamente a mi drive pero en produccion sigue el problema

Comment: Ok, dame 24 horas y te voy a dar la solución. Tengo que hacer pruebas primero.

Comment: @Morfinismo ya pasaron 24 horas jaja ojala vengas todavia no lo soluciono

Comment: Ya tengo la solución, pero pensé que ya lo habías solucionado. Al menos eso me dió a entender la edición que hiciste. Más al rato posteo el código. Ahorita estoy cuidando a mi hija.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución es buena para cargas sencillas, 10Mb o menos. Para cargas mayores a 10Mb es mejor si se hace por pedazos. No tengo mucho tiempo para explicar ahorita, pero te dejo el código. Cualquier duda, me contás en los comentarios.

```
<?php session_start();

//incluir la libreria del cliente de google php
require_once '../google-api-php-client-2.1.3/vendor/autoload.php';

//definir el alcance de permisos
$permisos = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');

//crear y configurar el objeto cliente
$cliente = new Google_Client();
$cliente->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php');
$cliente->setAuthConfig("ruta_a_llave.json");
$cliente->addScope($permisos);

//proceso para leer un archivo por pedazos
function leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo){
    $totalBytes = 0;
    $pedazoGigante = "";
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $pedazo = fread($fp, 8192);
        $totalBytes += strlen($pedazo);
        $pedazoGigante .= $pedazo;
        if ($totalBytes >= $bytesDelPedazo) {
            return $pedazoGigante;
        }
    }
    return $pedazoGigante;
}

if (isset($_SESSION["access_token"]) && $_SESSION["access_token"]) {

    $cliente->setAccessToken($_SESSION["access_token"]);
    $servicio = new Google_Service_Drive($cliente); // definir el serivico que se está solicitando

    $archivoLocal = "ruta/al/archivo.zip"; // definimos la ruta del archivo a cargar

    //preparar el archivo drive
    $archivoDrive = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
        array(
            'name' => 'nombre_del_archivo.zip',
            'parents' => array("1zx45Dt_z5dfer528dMg")
        )
    );
    $bytesDelPedazo = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //128Kbs

    //configurar los parámetros opcionales
    $paramsOpc = array(
        'fields' => '*'
    );

    //llamar a la api y configurar al cliente diferido para que no regrese inmediatamente
    $cliente->setDefer(true);
    $solicitud = $servicio->files->create($archivoDrive, $paramsOpc);

    //crear una carga de archivo multimedia para representar el proceso de carga
    $multimedia = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $cliente,
        $solicitud,
        "application/zip",
        null,
        true,
        $bytesDelPedazo
    );
    $multimedia->setFileSize(filesize($archivoLocal));

    //cargamos todos los pedazos. $estado será false hasta que el proceso esté completo
    $estado = false;
    $fp = fopen($archivoLocal, "rb");
    while (!$estado && !feof($fp)) {
        // leemos hasta que dejamos de obtener $bytesDelPedazo del $archivoLocal
        $pedazo = leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo);
        $estado = $multimedia->nextChunk($pedazo);
    }

    $cliente->setDefer(false);    
    //var_dump($estado);
    echo "Id del archvio: " . $estado->id;
    echo "Folder del archivo: " . $estado->parents;

} else {

    if (!isset($_GET["code"])) {

        $authUrl = $cliente->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($authUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    } else {

        $cliente->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $cliente->getAccessToken();

        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/index.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por reponder me comenta mi jefe que intente solucionar primero con el codigo que tengo antes de implementar todo , typpe=resumable e s para subir archivos con mayor peso pero no se como implementarlo. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil Suerte entonces. La otra manera es más compleja y lástima que no tengo tiempo para escribir detalladamente la implementación. Pensé que bastaría con una solución no un requerimiento en específico de tu jefe.

Comment: a mi si me sirve tu solucion y te  di por bien respondida la pregunta gracias pero el que manda es mi jefe y hasta que me de luz verde podre usar tu codigo gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: disculpa como puedo obtener el id y el folder de drive con tu metodo

Comment: ya casi queda ya guarda datos en la base de datos solo me falta el id y el folder peor creo que lo estoy haciendo mal, aqui es donde tendria que poner el folder verdad? "1zx45Dt_z5dfer528dMg"

Comment: acabo de agregar algo de codigo le puse en negritas nuevo codigo

Comment: me falta guardar el id y el folder de drive en la base de datos

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil Fijate que estás especificando que te regrese únicamente el link del archivo. Te recomiendo mejor usar `"fields" => "id,webContentLink,parents"` o si preferís obtener todo el recurso `"fields" => "*"`

Comment: ya lo intente pero nada jeje no me arroja el id seguire intentando

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil Perdón! No leí tu código bien porque ando en medio de juntas laborales. Acabo de modificar mi respuesta para claridad. Pon atención al la línea que dice `//configuramos los parámetros opcionales`

Comment: ya agregue las lineas que me indicaste pero no me arroja el id y el webcontentlink de la carpeta del drive , acabo de modificar el metodo de mi post si lo puedes ver cuando tengas tiempo por favor

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil Ya pude revisar el código con más tranquilidad y te pido disculpas. Era obvio que no te iba a tirar la información. La información del archivo la contiene el estado cuando la carga es completada. Acabo de editar el código para claridad. jajajaja.

Comment: muchas gracias  ya quedo @Morfinismo es la primera vez que veo goolgle api no le entendia nada .

Comment: maestro  @Morfinismo en que parte le asigno la ruta de la carpeta para que se guarde , me guarda los archivos en raiz.  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282852/asignar-ruta-a-google-drive-para-guardar-archivo