# asignar ruta a google drive para guardar archivo

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

¿en que parte se le asigna el parametro de la carpeta destino a google drive para que guarde el archivo?

me esta guardando en raiz el archivo y quiero que lo pongan en la carpeta estudios

en mi variable $folderId tengo la ruta

```
     function insertaArchivoDrive($service, $nombre_estudio, $folderId, $data,$ruta){
        // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.

        function leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo){
            $totalBytes = 0;
            $pedazoGigante = "";
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $pedazo = fread($fp, 8192);
                $totalBytes += strlen($pedazo);
                $pedazoGigante .= $pedazo;
                if ($totalBytes >= $bytesDelPedazo) {
                    return $pedazoGigante;
                }
            }
            return $pedazoGigante;
        }

        $archivoDrive = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $archivoDrive->setName($nombre_estudio);
        $archivoDrive->setDescription('A test zip');
        $archivoDrive->setMimeType('application/zip');

        $bytesDelPedazo = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //128Kbs

        $paramsOpc = array(
            'fields' => '*'
        );

        $this->client->setDefer(true);
        $solicitud = $service->files->create($archivoDrive,$paramsOpc);        
        $multimedia = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
            $this->client,
            $solicitud,
            "application/zip",
            null,
            true,
            $bytesDelPedazo
        );
        $multimedia->setFileSize(filesize($ruta));

        $estado = false;
        $fp = fopen($ruta, "rb");
        while (!$estado && !feof($fp)) {
            // leemos hasta que dejamos de obtener $bytesDelPedazo del $archivoLocal
            $pedazo = leerPorPedazos($fp, $bytesDelPedazo);
            $estado = $multimedia->nextChunk($pedazo);
        }
        echo "Id del archvio: " . $estado->id;
    echo "Folder del archivo: " . $estado->parents[0];
        //var_dump($estado);
        return $estado;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para asignar un folder en dónde se ha de guardar el archivo, hay que especificarlo en los metadatos del archivo. Hay dos formas de hacerlo; La forma que vos estás usando es poniendo cada valor llamando un método dentro del objeto. La otra es ponerlo todo usando un arreglo. Te dejo la demostración de ambas.

### La forma que vos estás usando

```
$archivoDrive = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$archivoDrive->setName($nombre_estudio);
$archivoDrive->setDescription('A test zip');
$archivoDrive->setMimeType('application/zip');
$archvioDrive->setParents(['id-del-folder']); //aquí se agrega el folder
```

### La otra forma

```
$archivoDrive = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => $nombre_estudio,
    'description' => 'A test zip',
    'mimeType' => 'application/zip',
    'parents' => ['id-del-folder'] //aquí se agrega el folder
));
```

Cualquiera de las dos da el mismo resultado. Yo prefiero la última porque me es más limpio para leer.

Comment: ya quedo muchas gracias quize quitar el array $paramsOpc = array(
            'fields' => '*'
        );  pense que no servia  y lo comente pero al quitarlo no me descargaba el archivo  ¿que hace ese array?

Comment: ese arreglo se encarga de especificar cuales propiedades mostrar cuando el archivo esté cargado. El asterisco representa el valor de **todas**